# Very Strange If Else results

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

If we have a webpage on port 1055, perfstat is installed.  It will update the spread sheet with either a yes or no.

Here is the strange thing.
    - Two Computers .. Computer1 has perfstat and Computer2 does not
    -  If I place Computer2 in the txt file first, the results come out correct.  False and         True-
    - If I place Computer1 first in the txt file, both machines come up as true! :(

I have something screwed up with the if statement.  As soon as it goes into the IF section, the results are incorrect.

Here is my code

```
$Computers = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\servers.txt


foreach ($Server in $computers)
{

    $reply = Invoke-WebRequest http://$Server":1055" | Select-Object Content

    if ($reply.Content -like "*Windows PerfStat v1.1.4*")
    {
        $Sheet1.Cells.Item($intRow, 1) = $server
        $Sheet1.Cells.Item($intRow, 2) = "Yes"
    }
    else
    {
        $Sheet1.Cells.Item($intRow, 1) = $server
        $Sheet1.Cells.Item($intRow, 2) = "No"
    }
    $intRow = $intRow + 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that Computer2 is not sending a result to feed into $reply. As such, if Computer1 is run first $Reply still has the same value when Computer2 runs. Add a `remove-variable reply` before your `$reply =` line:

```
foreach ($Server in $computers) {
if($reply){remove-variable reply}
$reply = Invoke-WebRequest http://$Server":1055" | Select-Object Content
```

Comment: exactly what i thought but was downloading powershell 4.0 to double check, still stuck on 2.0 for some reason :)